# Ibm mq Connection through standalone server]

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to connection to a ibm mq queue through standalone server.
(i am using 7.0.3 ibmmq jar)

```
cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "dcc");
          cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 14321);
          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "dfds");
          cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "dw");
          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, "ww");
          cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, "vw");
```

i have set all these properties in connection Factory.
Conenction is made successfully but i am unable to open queue. getting the following error.

```
**MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '6114'.**
FAILED: Queueconnection
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'US.0732931.NGEN.MANIFEST.LOADS'.
JMS attempted to perform an MQOPEN, but WebSphere MQ reported an error.
Use the linked exception to determine the cause of this error. Check that the specified queue and queue manager are defined correctly.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:585)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
```

Comment: Are you using AMS (Advanced Message Security)?  Is there more to the stack trace than you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't provide enough information.

- What connection factory are you using?
- The error happens on the MQOPEN but you do NOT show the code for your createQueue method which is the ***important***

Here's sample code:

```
private void putMessage()
{
   JmsConnectionFactory cf = null;
   Connection connection = null;
   Session session = null;
   Destination reqQ = null;
   MessageProducer producer = null;

   try
   {
      // Create a connection factory
      JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);

      cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "MY_QMGR_NAME");
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, "MY_TEST_CHL");
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "some_remote_server");
      cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, 1414);
      cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, "my_uid");
      cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, "my_pwd");

      // Create JMS objects
      connection = cf.createConnection();
      connection.start();
      session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

      /**
       *  Create destination to send requests
       *  - MQA1 is the queue manager name
       *  - TEST.Q1 is the queue name
       */
      reqQ = session.createQueue("queue://MQA1/TEST.Q1");

      // Create producer
      producer = session.createProducer(reqQ);
      // Create a message
      Message myMsg = session.createTextMessage("This is a test message.");
      // Send it
      producer.send(myMsg);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      System.err.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
   }
   finally
   {
      try
      {
         session.close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.err.println("session.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
      }

      try
      {
         connection.close();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.err.println("connection.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
      }
   }
}
```